# Django auto detecting passed forms to the template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In the past, I named all my forms as `form` and at the base.html template I used `{{ form.errors }}` to catch all the errors,

Now I have variously named different forms at many different views yet I want to keep this form error catching generic, how can I detect all passed forms and iterate through them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is available to your template unless it's in the context. Since you manage the context for each view, I'm not sure what the problem is here. It doesn't matter what your form is named in the view, you can simply pass it to the context as "form":

```
render_to_response('template.html', {
    'form': some_crazy_form_name,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If you have one view with multiple forms, you could simply provide a context variable called 'forms' and make it a list:

```
render_to_response('template.html', {
    'forms': [first_form, second_form]
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or even better as a dictionary, so you could know which form is which:

```
render_to_response('template.html', {
    'forms': {
        'alpha': first_form,
        'beta': second_form,
    },
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The idea, is that you can pretty much do whatever you like. Just set the context up how you want and then use it in your template. Where's the problem?

Comment: the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is also an option in Django 1.3

Comment: Yep, but since `render_to_response` still works in 1.3, I wrote the example code such that it would work with any version of Django (the OP didn't specify which version they're running).